# JAVA Recursive bisection method

Tags: java, recursion

```
    private double EPSILON = 0.25;
    private int iteration = 0;

    public double f(double x){
        return x*x - 2;
    }

    public double bisection(double a, double b){ //main algorithm

        iteration++;

        if(f(a) * f(b) >= 0){
            return 0.0; // Wrong [a, b]
        }

        double c = a;
        while((b-a) >= EPSILON){

            c = (a+b)/2; // middle point

            if(f(c) == 0.0){ // that means middle point is the root
                break;
            }
            else if (f(c)*f(a) < 0){
                b = c;
                bisection(a, b); // continue calculating by recu
            }
            else{
                a = c;
                bisection(a, b);
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    public int getIteration(){
        return iteration;
    }
}
```

I am dealing with a recursive bisection method/algorithm. I've put my recursion in the else/else if statement and don't know if I'm wrong or not. It also returns the correct root without recursion there, but the main issue is to do that with recursion.

Comment: If you are using recursion then you don't need a loop here. Just try it without any loops and see how far you get.

Comment: I've replaced the 'while' statement with the 'if' statement. Now it returns the wrong root, but after debugging I saw that at the 5th iteration my root is correct, but for now, have no idea how to catch it.

Comment: Yes, it still has bugs. The comparisons where you are multiplying function outputs together don't make sense to me.

Comment: Okay, I found the way out. The problem was ` double c = a`. Now it works, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the way out.

```
    private double EPSILON = 0.25;
    private int iteration = 0;
    private double c = 1.0;

    public double f(double x){
        return x*x - 2;
    }

    public double bisection(double a, double b){ //main algorithm

        iteration++;

        if(f(a) * f(b) >= 0){
            return 0.0; // Wrong [a, b]
        }

        if((b-a) >= EPSILON){

            c = (a+b)/2; // middle point

            if(f(c) == 0.0){ // that means middle point is the root
                return c;
            }
            else if (f(c)*f(a) < 0){
                b = c;
                bisection(a, b);
            }
            else {
                a = c;
                bisection(a, b);
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    public int getIteration(){
        return iteration;
    }
}
```